# Connecting to multiple servers from a single client socket C

Tags: c, sockets

I have a single client that is trying to connect to my main server using socket s1. The client needs to keep trying to connect to main server with s1, but at the same time connect and keep sending "trying" messages to my secondary server. Is it a good idea to create 2 sockets,reuse port and create 2 binds for those 2 sockets or there are better ways to achieve this? This is a client side and using C sockets. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your program is a client to multiple servers, use one socket per server. You don't need `bind` for a client socket at all, just `connect`.

Comment: Thanks.Wasn't sure about bind.Now using 1 socket per server.

Comment: @Fred Foo so a client can connect to multiple servers with different IPs(off course ) on the same port on client side?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using TCP socket( aren't you?). So one socket for connection is needed. 
Then reuse port is not so important because your application is a client application, which is the part the start the connection. Any outbound port should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can only call `connect(2)` once per stream-oriented socket, you really must use at least two sockets to make two simultaneous connections (or connection attempts).

You don't need to `bind(2)` anything on client ports, except in strange cases. (I'm thinking of the Sun RPC portmapper daemon, but thankfully it's been nearly a decade since I've cared about the portmapper daemon. Also `rlogin` needed to `bind(2)` as a client when using the host-authentication method, which was horrible.)