# Creation of multiple sockets on a client

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have a situation where a client needs to be connected to multiple servers. According to the question answered here :
[Connecting to multiple servers from a single client socket C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402019/connecting-to-multiple-servers-from-a-single-client-socket-c)

I would need to create a single socket to connect to every server. What I'm trying to ask is: is there a more efficient way to go about this apart from repeating this piece of code to create multiple sockets? many thanks!

```
//Create a socket for the client
//If sockfd<0 there was an error in the creation of the socket
if ((sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) <0) {
    perror("Problem in creating the socket");
    exit(2);
}

//Creation of the socket
memset(&client1addr, 0, sizeof(client1addr));
client1addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
client1addr.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr(argv[1]);
client1addr.sin_port =  htons(SERV_PORT); //convert to big-endian order

//Connection of the client to the socket
if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client1addr, sizeof(client1addr))<0) {
    perror("Problem in connecting to the server");
    exit(3);
}
```

Comment: Well, you should be using `getaddrinfo` instead of `inet_addr`, and that will cut out _some_ of the boilerplate (but add other boilerplate) -- but no, in general, you will have to call `socket`, `getaddrinfo`, and `connect` for each server.  Usually what people do is wrap this sequence up in a function.

Comment: You're also going to want to read up on `select`.  And you might find [`libevent`](http://libevent.org/) helpful.

Comment: @zwol thank you for your help!

Comment: @zwol would it be possible to use pthreads/fork instead of select? upon reading about select, it seems like it cannot handle multiple connections concurrently...

Comment: The very purpose of `select`(or `poll`) is to handle multiple connections concurrently.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck i found this tutorial here and in the comments section it says that it cannot handle concurrent connections.. is it because of how select is used in this example? http://www.binarytides.com/multiple-socket-connections-fdset-select-linux/

Comment: @user1816546 The commenter called Jesus is incorrect. `select` makes it possible to handle multiple connections in a single thread. It takes a bit of doing since a stable implementation needs to be able to handle partial reads/writes. With that I mean that the entire message may not be readable/writable at once, so you read/write what you can and then call `select` again. I've been meaning to write an example in Documentation, but I've never gotten around to it.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification! yeah, there don't seem to be many examples using select() since pthreads seem to be more popular... would you be able to post some quick pseudo code as answer to this question please?

Comment: @user1816546 The example you linked is actually fairly good. It doesn't handle writes using select, so a client can hang it by sending a lot of data and not reading the replies. But other than that I think it does a good job explaining the concept of handling multiple connections in a single thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138545/discussion-between-user1816546-and-klas-lindback).

Comment: According to the duplicate you need one socket per target server.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem in trying to reuse the same socket for different connections is that a socket connection must store not only the local part of the connection (host and port numbers) but also the remote ones(remote host and remote port)  The purpose of this info is to reach the proper socket when some data packet arrives to a host, is must select the right socket based only on the packet contents and nothing else.  So trying to connect the same socket to different remote places is not possible with only one socket.  Normally the problem here is that you think on a socket as something ideal that could be how our needs dictate instead of something that must obey protocol rules.  A connected socket must define this four quantities and once assigned (this meaning once connected) you cannot make it overlap more connections.

By the way, socket creation is something that has been optimized so getting a new socket is cheap in terms of resources.

If even this solution is not affordable, you have the chance of switching to a connectionless protocol (like udp) where a socket is ready to receive packets as soon as you have bound it to a host address and client port, so it can receive any packet directed to that ip address and port.  This way, you can manage data arriving from different sources with only a socket (for example, this has been used in many p2p protocols) but you'll have to cope with dropped, repeated and changed in transit packets yourself.