# Connect client to multiple servers in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I would like to create a client which connects to multiple servers (say, 5 servers). The client needs to send different data to these 5 servers. I have looked into select(), pthreads, and fork () however all the examples I find rely on accept() to create a new socket.

Since this is a client, I found that I do not need to call bind (), accept() etc. : [Connecting to multiple servers from a single client socket C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402019/connecting-to-multiple-servers-from-a-single-client-socket-c)

Basically, what I would like to do is as follows:

On the client side:

- Create 5 sockets
- use connect () to connect these sockets to the 5 servers
- send the data to these servers concurrently
- receive this data back in the client

Could anyone please post some pseudo code/ link me to some resources to achieve what I need?

Comment: This is currently too broad.  You seem to know that you need to create a socket and use `connect`, so start by doing that with one server, then once you have that working expand it to 5.    If you have a more specific question, post that along with all relevant code.

Comment: I think this question might be able to help you - it's very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903611/creation-of-multiple-sockets-on-a-client ;)

Comment: @dbush I have it working for one server, I just don't know how to expand it to 5... this is where I am currently stuck with no idea how to proceed. Should I post my client code?

Comment: @ChrisTurner I already posted that question, where they suggested using select, however I cannot find what I need :(

Comment: So it sounds like you need a separate thread for each socket.  So use `pthread_create` to create as many threads as you need, then have each thread service a socket.

Comment: @dbush do you know of any examples I can look at please?

Comment: @user1816546 Start with the [man page for `pthread_create`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) and go from there.